# Spring MVC 4 for REST Controller, how to autowire different dependencies for test cases

Tags: java, spring, junit

Let's say you have a controller like so and you want to change the autowired dependency.  What are ways to have one implementation for your project under /src/main/java and then have a mock dependency in your test code under /src/test/java.  The code under /src/main/java will get built into the web application.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/u/util/")
public class HealthCheckAdapter {
    @Autowired    
    private HealthDbService healthCheck;

}
```

The HealthDbService is a Java interface, and here an example concrete class.  I could change the qualifier below, but Spring will still pick this up in the test cases?

```
@Repository
@Qualifier("basicHealthCheckService")
public class HealthCheckDefaultManager implements HealthDbService {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest, recommended way: use constructor injection:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/u/util/")
public class HealthCheckAdapter {
    private HealthDbService healthCheck;

    @Autowired // not even needed in recent versions
    public HealthCheckAdapter(HealthDbService healthCheck) {
        this.healthCheck = healthCheck;
    }
}
```

And now in your unit test:

```
new HealthCheckAdapter(new FakeHealthDbService());
```

or, using a mocking API like Mockito:

```
HealthDbService mockHealthDbService = mock(HealthDbService.class);
new HealthCheckAdapter(mockHealthDbService);
```

If you use Mockito, it can also [inject mock dependencies](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#9) using annotations, even if you keep using field injection.

And finally, if you want to use mock MVC tests (to test the annotations, the JSON serialization, etc.), you can use the [Spring testing support](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#testing) (which is even easier to use in Spring Boot)

Comment: Question, if you don't specify through the qualifier and annotation, let's say I have two concrete classes I want to use in /src/main/java.  Which one will get used?  In the example, how does the container know which to use say in the controller above for a live, non-test example.

Comment: It doesn't. You'll have to tell Spring.

Comment: I could setup I think there is a primary qualifier